# can memcache be used only with one server?

Tags: caching, memcached

i want to know if i can use memcache, but im only using one server, and i heard that memcache has to work with only 2 servers or more? i just want to clarify this?

Comment: sorry, i know its a random question, but i really wanted to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcached can be used on the same server as your webserver.  It's just a running process that accepts incoming connections, which can come from the same machine.